Circular motion finding points on the route
I need help, have been racking my brain for two days without success
I have a plane that is given several parameters: starting point (x,y), speed in a straight line (it is constant), the starting direction of the plane (azimth) and its minimum turning radius and it can only turn clockwise.
A cycle time is also given, and it is necessary during the cycle time to update the updated point of the plane. At first the plane flies straight and everything is fine and I manage to calculate the next point, the problem is when it's a circular route I can't calculate its next points.
I don't have a given angle, only the plane's direction is north, meaning if it's in a 30 degree direction, it doesn't mean that the declination from the center of its circle to the starting point is 30, it's just its direction.
I would appreciate the help, thank you
i tried using x(t)=x0 +Rcos(θ(t)) and y(t)=y0+Rsin(θ(t)) but i cant find θ because only azimth is given not θ dont know how to find the link between them

You can't just compute x(t).  It's a continuous process.  You compute x(t+1) and y(t+1) from x(t), y(t), and theta(t).  I'll make an example.

Do you know the formula for the circumference of a circle? Do you know the length of an arc with radius R through angle θ?

Here's some Python code that demonstrates the process.  "dxy" is the velocity of the plane in units per second.  "dtheta" is the yaw rate of the plane in degrees per second.  This should end up with a circle.
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 10
y = 10
dxy = 1
theta = 0
dtheta = 1
xx = [x]
yy = [y]

for i in range(360):
    print(i,x,y)
    dx = dxy * math.cos(math.radians(theta))
    dy = dxy * math.sin(math.radians(theta))

    x += dx
    y += dy
    theta = (theta + dtheta) % 360
    xx.append(x)
    yy.append(y)

plt.plot(xx,yy)
plt.show()

And, indeed, it does  Note that I started the aircraft at 10,10, and since I'm using Cartesian angles instead of aviationangles, 0 is to the right and the numbers increase counter-clockwise.  You an overcome that by using "thetax = 270 - theta".

